# How to set column names in PHP/SQL generated .csv spreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export, spreadsheet

I found the following script on the web and edited it to my needs, but the one thing I'm not able to figure out is how to change the column names. AS-is, the column names show up in the spreadsheet as the name of the corresponding column in the database. is there a way to change this?

thanks for any advice!
here's my code:

```
<?php
$host = 'asdf';
$user = 'asdf';
$pass = 'asdf';
$db = 'asdf';
$table = 'stats';
$file = 'export';

    $fields = "date, name, time, inbset, asapset, faxset, obset, totset, inbclo, asapclo, faxclo, obclo, totclo, inbtot, asaptot, faxtot, obtot, total, comments";

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d");

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field'].", ";
$i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM ".$table."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way? :Yes there is. Is there more room for improvement as well? :Yes there is. Any more questions?

Comment: thanks, buddy, but that doesn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names are coming from the first row in your CSV output.

Around line 20:
`$csv_output .= $row['Field'].", "`;

Simply remove that block of code, and output a line of column names like you wish:
"Column Name 1, Column Name 2, Column Name 3, ..."

Comment: do i still need the . in front of the =? i'm still learning and i don't quite understand why that's there?

Comment: Remove the entire block from line 16-24. Replace it with simple output of your column names.  FYI, .= concatenates the string with an additional value while = assigns a new value.

Comment: for anyone else who might run into this.. the bottom part that outputs the actual data is dependent on some part of the code between lines 26-24. i'm a noob so i'm not sure what yet but i solved the problem by removing the line `$csv_output .= $row['Field'].", "` and placing it undeneith line 24 right before this part `\n`.. i'm sure that's not the healthiest way to do it but it finally works..

Answer (score 2):

The code you have there - probably copy and pasted instead of written by your own and understood - is schizophrenic.

On the one hand it does define the column names on top:

```
    $fields = "date, name, time, inbset, asapset, faxset, obset, totset, inbclo, asapclo, faxclo, obclo, totclo, inbtot, asaptot, faxtot, obtot, total, comments";
```

On the other hand it reads them from the database:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
```

I suggest you create a second variable that just contains the column names for the CSV file and just put it as first line into the file. Job done.

Comment: `$filed` sets the fields i want to export. prevents me from having to export all of them. and like i said, i found the script on the web and edited as best i could. i'm still learning. instead of picking on me why don't help me out?

Comment: I'm not picking on you, I gave a tip: Do not copy and paste, but *write* your own. You can still copy, but type it yourself. You will see that you learn more even you might think *"I'm typing something I do not fully understand"* - your brain manages that better. It won't adopt to a copy and paste that well.

Answer (score 1):

The lines that produce the header row are:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field'].", ";
$i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
```

So, to head the header row as you wish, you need to modify this code.
It will save you a database query too if you don't need this

Answer (score 0):

you should use "AS" while selecting.

for example i got a table people:

```
id,username,name,birth
1,alpera,aykutalper,1985
```

if i use

```
select username from people where id=1;
this returns
|username|
|alpera  |
```

if i use

```
select username as user from people where id=1;
this returns
|user    |
|alpera  |
```

i hope that is what you want.